# PHP won't display Echo statement

Tags: php

I'm having trouble checking as to why my echo statement does not appear. I am using a web hosting service so I can use PHP scripts (double checked using simple echo "Hello World!" PHP scripts before). My file does have a .php file extension.

My goal is to simply add two numbers using PHP function from two inputs and just display the result.

```
    <body>
    <div>

    <form action="index.php">

      Enter First Number:<br>
      <input type="text" name="first_input" value="">
      <br>

      Enter Second Number:<br>
      <input type="text" name="second_input" value=""><br>

      <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
    </form> 

    <?php           
                    function Calc_Addition() {     

                    $first_input = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'first_input');
                    $second_input = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'second_input');

                    $amount_output = $first_input + $second_input;
                    echo "$amount_output";

                    }

    ?> 

    </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: You never call the `Calc_Addition()` function, so none of the code in it ever executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to both parse the input values as numbers (or pass them as such) and execute the function you're calling, like so:

```
<body>
<div>

    <form action="index.php" method="get">

    Enter First Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="first_input" value="">
    <br>

    Enter Second Number:<br>
    <input type="text" name="second_input" value=""><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form> 

<?php           
            function Calc_Addition() {     
                $first_input = intval($_GET['first_input']);
                $second_input = intval($_GET['second_input']);

                $amount_output = $first_input + $second_input;
                echo $amount_output;

            }

            if(isset($_GET['first_input'])) { 
                 Calc_Addition(); 
            }
?> 
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the suggestion on what to change. I'm a disappointed I didn't think to change the inputs to numbers. And thanks to all who answered! I'm reading all the comments before and after I typed this up and try to absorb it. And thanks for the isset stuff too for checking.

Comment: No problem!  Don't forget to "accept" the answer that helped you (by clicking the check mark below the down arrow).  If you're still having problems let me know -- I've tutored PHP plenty of times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the function. You aren't doing so

```
<body>
<div>

<form action="index.php">

  Enter First Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="first_input" value="">
  <br>

  Enter Second Number:<br>
  <input type="text" name="second_input" value=""><br>

  <input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form> 

<?php           
                //Check if isset, then execute function
                if (isset($_GET['first_input'])) { 
                     Calc_Addition(); 
                 }

                function Calc_Addition() {     

                $first_input = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'first_input');
                $second_input = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'second_input');

                $amount_output = $first_input + $second_input;
                echo "$amount_output";

                }

?> 

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: You might also want to check if the form was actually sent before calling the function. Like: `if (isset($_GET['first_input'])) { Calc_Addition(); }`

Comment: also, change the input types from text to number

Comment: ...and you can remove the unnecessary quotes around `$amount_output` in the echo (or rather echo the addition straight away, without the extra step of storing the result in a variable).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to cast your $first_input and $second_input variables as int's before adding them. So $amount_output would read as follows:

```
$amount_output = intval($first_input) + intval($second_input);
```

Comment: If the values are numbers, PHP will cast them automatically.